# Routing to private routes with React, it renders the wrong route first. How to solve this?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm writing a private route for an application and I'm trying to keep a user logged in after I refresh the app. To solve this I created a function that checks if the user saved in localStorage is valid with the checkAuthenticated function inside useEffect fetching a jwtoken to the server and setting the isAuthenticated state accordingly.

My problem is that every time I refresh, it renders the Login route and THEN reroutes to the Main component with a logged in user. (Main is also a Switch with other routes inside and it defaults to the main route, so I lose where I was before the refresh, but that's a different issue :S

I also tried doing everything through redux because my user info is in a redux state. The verify prop is an action that does the same as checkAuthenticated and isValid is a boolean equivalent to isAuthenticated.

Here's a sample of my App component. Can anyone help me solve this?

```
const App = ({ user, verify, isValid }) => {
const [ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated ] = useState(false);

useEffect( () => {
  console.log("USEEFFECT RUNS")
  checkAuthenticated();
}, [])

return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/login"
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <LoginComponent {...props} setAuth={setIsAuthenticated}/>
      }
    />
    <Route
      path="/"
      component={ () =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Main /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin I would heavily suggest not using localStorage for tracking if a user is authenticated or not, it is far from secure and is editable client side. Instead, I would suggest using http cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

When your application is first rendered `isAuthenticated` is equal to `false`.
This causes your Route to redirect to the Login page. After checking localStorage and confirming the JWT token, `isAuthenticated` is then set to `true`, component is rerendered, and the correct page is displayed. This is the path your app will take, and that is why I believe you are getting the Login page first on refresh even though you are authenticated.

A potential "hacky" fix to ensure this is the cause could be setting isAuthenticated to null, and then to true/false depending on the result of the JWT token check. In the render, check if isAuthenticated is null (===) and if not, check false/true then.

In conclusion, you need to know the difference between "Have not checked for JWT", "Has Checked: No JWT", and "Has Checked: Confirmed JWT".

Comment: Also, I'm not sure a `useEffect` hook is even needed here since checking localStorage is not asynchronous. You should be able to just check it with a `useLocalStorage` custom hook. https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

Comment: what I do is to store a token in localStorage and then send that token on a request to the server. Then the response tells me if the token/user is valid or not. That's what I do with useEffect.

Comment: gotcha, I figured it was something like that but couldn't see the `checkAuthenticated` function. then yes, you need a `isLoading` state to see if the JWT verification request has finished, and then you would check true/false on isAuthenticated.